# Display the table of a shapefile in Google Earth Engineer apps UI interface

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, user-interface, interface

I'm trying to insert a table similar to the one in the attached image. Would anyone have any idea where to start?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/475917a534535468d35beb6c57623ca9

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, not a "Where to start?" one. Our Focused question/Best answer model isn't well-suited for initial research. I suggest you locate a tutorial, and if you then have code that doesn't work as expected, you'd have the basis for a Question.